# Favorite Tags and Highlight Question

Tags: support, tag-watching

My Favorite Tags are `C#` and many more.When I search a question using C# key word its gives a result but some question are highlighted and some are not.

[image: Snapshot]

Before this I think all *Favorite Tags* question are highlighted. I don't understand the real relation between *Favorite Tags* and *Highlight Question*. I searched on meta but was unable to find about this. Am I missing something to understand about Favorite Tags and Highlight Question? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are viewing a specified tag, the questions with more than one tags in your favorite list will be highlighted.

so questions tagged with "C#, .net" or "c#, jquery" or "c#, asp.net" will be highlighted.

Comment: i think you mean "c#, jquery" instead of "c#, json", cause the does not favorite `json`

Comment: @Jehof yes, you got me.

Comment: comment my own answer ss